# Java code to run command on remote Linux with sesu access

Tags: java, ssh

I need java code that logs into linux box with my credentials, then do a sesu , and then execute a shell script. Permission to execute the shell script if for only sesu user, hence sesu-ing after login is critical. I used te following code which can help me execute a command with my credential scope, however, I need sesu login following my login. Please suggest a way.
I tried adding the sesu command in teh command list, but it prompts for a password. I want a way to pass the password as well and completly automate it.

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

    public class SSHCommandExecutor {
        /** * @param args */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String host = "xxxxxxx";
            String user = "xxxxxxx";
            String password = "xxxxxxx";
            String command1 = "cd /test; ./test.sh";
            try {
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "sesu"? What's that? I do not see it in your code.

Comment: Could you please indent your code correctly to make it easier to read?

Comment: I have indented the code. Hope it is better in understanding

Comment: Sesu is a way to execute a command as another user in linux box with their permission access. **String command1 = "cd /test; sesu -usre2; ./test.sh";**
If I try above command , it asks for password and the code hangs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variant A: Using JSch all the way**

This minimal script (`test.sh`) requests an input from stdin before putting out one line of data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Is this a good question (y/n)? "
read answer
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
fi
```

So it should be equivalent to your call requesting a password to be given. Now have a look at this code on how to send data into that process

```
String command1 = "cd /home/jan; ./test.sh";
try {
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected");
    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
    OutputStream o = channel.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(o);
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);

    channel.connect();

    // 1 - Reading the prompt to input password
    byte[] buf = new byte[255];
    int len = in.read(buf);
    System.out.println(new String(buf,0,len));

    // 2 - Send (password) data and flush stream
    pw.println("y");
    pw.flush();

    // 3 - Read result
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());

    // 4 - Clean up
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

**Variant B: Shell magic**

```
String command1 = "cd /test; echo 'password' | ./test.sh";
```

or

```
String command1 = "cd /test; ./test.sh <<< 'password'";
```

(of cause you'd need to specify correct password there)

To run remote script with root privileges even if login user does not have them see here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Comment: Tried all 3 ways and none of them works. Variant A code hangs (probably beacuse sesu is a command in Linux)and the variant B is not passing password properly.

Comment: The user I amn trying to SESU in is an admin user, and we cannot have that password.

Comment: It is a great way to execute scripts as root. Unfortunatly we donot have sudo in the linux box and donto have the permission to add it either. So i need to go via SESU route only.

Comment: Linux XXXXXXX 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux .

Comment: LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.8
Codename:       Tikanga

Comment: $ /usr/seos/bin/sesu -n -f XXXXXXX
-n (do not ask invoker password) is not valid when sesu is invoked by a none root user.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. You cannot outsmart sesu to not request a password from a terminal, you cannot bypass password prompt, you cannot (as you told before) have sudo setup for your script but still you insist you need to run script as root. I'd suggest you talk again to the sysadmins of the linux box and ask their opinion on how to give your script root access

Comment: Thx janschweizer for all the help.Really appreciate it.